# Adding Ids to an Array

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

I tried adding an `id` property to the objects in my sorted output, but all I'm doing is not working. Is there anything I should have done?

My Code Below:

```js
var arr = [{ one: 2 }, 
           { two: 3 }, 
           { three: 4 },
           { four: 1 }];
const arr1 = arr.reduce((a,b) => ({...a,...b}), {}) 
var sorting = Object.entries(arr1).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
console.log(sorting);
```

Expected Result:

```
var arr1 = [{ name: "three", value: 4, id: 1 }, 
            { name: "two", value: 3, id: 2 },
            { name: "one", value: 2, id: 3 },
            { name: "four", value: 1, id: 4 }];
```

Comment: You could possibly use push to add new itens to arry and pop to remove itrms

Comment: Did you mean: "Expected Result of arr1: `[['three', 4 id = 1], ['two', 3 id = 2], ['one', 2 id = 3], ['four', 1 id = 4]]`"?

Comment: Do you want a reverse sort (descending) by values of properties of objects in `arr` array?

Comment: Yes @iAmOren Exactly

Comment: And the items in the array (`arr1`) - what should they be?
`{text:"three", value:4, id:1}` - for example?
Because, how it looks, it's not an object, neither an array...

Comment: I mean exactly your first question. But How's that possible with my code above

Comment: your expected output is quite odd to me and actually will not work with a trailing comma on the array in JavaScript and is an invalid JavaScript object.

Comment: Are you positive you want an invalid object and not an objject with an array of objects something like? `var arr1 ={myArray:[{'three': 4, id :1}, {'two':3 ,id :2}, {'one': 2, id :3}, {'four':1, id : 4}]};` or possibly just an array of objects `var arr1 =[{'three': 4, id :1}, {'two':3 ,id :2}, {'one': 2, id :3}, {'four':1, id : 4}];`

Comment: Can you guild how i can actually archive this  {text:"three", value:4, id:1}  or [{text:"three", value:4, id:1}, {text:"three", value:4, id:1}]  with my code above

Comment: I don't understand the `id` property in your comment here. Always 1? How is it determined? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.assign` can do what you did with `reduce`, and I would not call that result `arr1`, as it is not an array, but a plain object.
In the final step it helps to use destructuring and map to an object literal with shortcut notation:

```js
const arr = [{one: 2}, {two: 3}, {three: 4}, {four: 1}];
const obj = Object.assign({}, ...arr); 
const sorted = Object.entries(obj).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
const result = sorted.map(([text, value], i) => ({ text, value, id: i+1}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: How can I add images next to id; say I have an array of images like const images=["img1", "img2", "img3" ] then I have text, value, id images (picking from an array of IMages) @trincot

Comment: You can add more to the final object, like `{ text, value, id: i+1, img: images[i] }`. But that was not in your question? If you have more questions, then please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*If i console.log(sorting) I have  
[['three', 4 ], ['two', 3 ], ['one', 2 ], ['four', 1 ],]
  Without Ids but i want something like the expected result below*/

/*  Expected Result 
[['three', 4 id = 1], ['two', 3 id = 2], ['one', 2 id = 3], ['four', 1 id = 4],]
  */
```

UPD, sorry, didn't get it right first time

```js
var empty = [];

var arr = [{
  one: 2
}, {
  two: 3
}, {
  three: 4
},{
  four: 1
}];
const arr1 = arr.reduce((a,b) => ({...a,...b}), {}) 
const sorting = Object.entries(arr1).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
// Add indexes starting from 1
const indexed = sorting.map((a,b) => a.push({ "id": b+1 }));

console.log(sorting);
```

Comment: this is not the expected (albeit invalid) output the OP has - as stated this is actually unanswerable due to that invalid object desired (yours is valid and is likely what is desired but difficult to discern given the OP statements

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go with a guess here that you want a descending sorted array of objects, adding an `id` property based on the original `index + 1` of each original object.  We can do that by reference to the object key (first property 0) when we sort after we add the ids to the original objects in a new array.

```js
// not used in the question/issue 
//var empty = [];

var arr = [{
  one: 2
}, {
  two: 3
}, {
  three: 4
}, {
  four: 1
}];

const newArr = [];
arr.forEach(function(currentValue, index, arr) {
  currentValue.id = index + 1;
  newArr.push(currentValue);
}, arr);
//console.log("arrObj:", newArr);
var sorted = newArr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b[Object.keys(b)[0]] - a[Object.keys(a)[0]];
});
console.log("sorted:", sorted);
```

EDIT: new based on comment

```js
var arr = [{
  one: 2
}, {
  two: 3
}, {
  three: 4
}, {
  four: 1
}];

const newArr = [];
arr.forEach(function(currentValue, index, arr) {
  let newValue = {};
  newValue.text = Object.keys(currentValue)[0];
  newValue.Value = currentValue[Object.keys(currentValue)[0]];
  newValue.id = index + 1;
  newArr.push(newValue);
}, arr);
//console.log("arrObj:", newArr);
var sorted = newArr.sort(function(a, b) {

  return b.Value - a.Value;
});
console.log("sorted:", sorted);
```

output of this last is

```
sorted: [
  {
    "text": "three",
    "Value": 4,
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "text": "two",
    "Value": 3,
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "text": "one",
    "Value": 2,
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "text": "four",
    "Value": 1,
    "id": 4
  }
]
```